# Nothing shows in all mail on the Galaxy Note 5

Tags: gmail

I just purchased the Galaxy Note 5 and I'm using the Gmail app. All of the labels work fine except the all mail.  When I go to all labels I see that next to the name "All Mail" I have 99+ messages but when I click on "all mail" I get a message that says "there is no mail here".  I use this folder quite often so this is discouraging.  I can see it on my laptop and iPhone just fine. It also worked fine on my Galaxy Note 4.  Any suggestions?

When I go to 'manage label' the all mail says "sync:all, which says all messages will download when connected.  Any advice?